# Promise warning after a mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I am new with nodejs. I have this code:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  User.findAll({
    attributes: [
      '_id',
      'name',
      'email',
      'role',
      'provider'
    ]
  })
    .then(function(users) {
      res.status(200).json(users);
    })
    .catch(handleError(res));
};

function handleError(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 500;
  return function(err) {
    res.status(statusCode).send(err);
  };
}
```

And I received this warning when it is executed:

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
>
> at [object Object].Model.findAll (C:\aii\tema2-node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1329:18)

Do you know why I received that warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share User.findAll and handleError?

Comment: The stack shows that the library is Sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to return the User.findAll

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  return User.findAll({
    attributes: [
      '_id',
      'name',
      'email',
      'role',
      'provider'
    ]
  })
    .then(function(users) {
      res.status(200).json(users);
    })
    .catch(handleError(res));
};
```

Comment: I think `exports.index` is an Express handler.

Comment: Doesn't matter. User.findAll returns a promise, which is not returned. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: Technically, what's being returned is the promise of either the `.then()` or the `catch()`. I explained it a little more in my answer below along with a generalized refactoring.

Comment: Anyhow he must return the promise to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the original code:

1. The exported function doesn't return anything. How do callers know if anything succeeded or not?
2. The `.then()` handler does not return anything which results in it's promise resolving with a value of `undefined` (remember that `then()` returns a promise as well `catch()`).
3. Even if the module function returned the promise chain (like in the answer above) it would still resolve to `undefined` due to the above.

I would most likely refactor your code to something like the psuedocode below. I'm going to assume that you are using something like express

```
 var User = require("<your User module>");
 //assuming app has been initialized...
 app.get("/users", (req,res) => {
       User.findAll({
                      attributes: [
                      '_id',
                      'name',
                      'email',
                      'role',
                      'provider']
                     })        
                     .then((users) => {
                         res.status(200).json(users); 
                     })
                     .catch((err) => {
                        //ideally send a generalized msg instead
                        res.status(500, {error: err } ); 
                     });
 });
```

Here there aren't any consumers of the promises returned by `then()` or `catch()` so it's not a big deal if they return `undefined`

Comment: You're wrong that the .then returns nothing. It returns undefined and the promise will resolve perfectly.

Comment: You're right, the code in your example will definitely resolve. I was referring to the code in the original question. Additionally, a promise is supposed to represent an eventual value or an error. It doesn't make much sense to have it return undefined (even though it's spec compliant) unless you're using it in the context in my example where you have no consumers of the promise.